# What is exactly it mean that associating a number of user threads to kernel level threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, scheduling

I am reading Galvin's OS concepts. There it is stated that there must exist some relation between user level threads and kernel level then they explained what is all kind of relation widely used. But they didn't explicitly mention what is an "association" is. 
From the context they used the term, I guess number concurrent system call that a group of threads can make(possibly all belongs to a particular process). Is my guess correct?
What are we going to achieve by associating user level threads with kernel level threads?

Answer (score 0):

Are you are referring to the secion "Multithreading Models" in the "Threads" chapter?

If so, then it's quickly explained:

Threads are either managed by the OS (kernel), or they are kind-of emulated by a non-kernel process. Today, a thread in a (native) program corresponds to exactly one kernel-managed thread. Those threads are known to the OS an can be scheduled by the OS's scheduler as needed.

Some programs choose to implement threading-like functionality themselves. One prominent example of which is the Python interpreter: While the Python language provides support for multi-threading, the interpreter will only run with a single OS/kernel thread and will take care to switch execution between the code of different Python threads itself; that's the "many-to-one" mapping: Multiple Python threads run on a single OS thread. Early versions of the Java VM did similar emulation, but I can't seem to remember if it was the "many-to-one" or "many-to-many" style.